# How to copy a directory in ant without modifying the sub directories last modified date

Tags: file-io, ant, copy, last-modified

**Problem:**

I have an ant task where I want to copy a folder to a new location but keep all the sub directories last modified date unchanged.

**Attempt 1:** 
Looking at the docs I found the preservelastmodified attribute on the copy ant task. I tried that and it preserved the last modified date for the files but not the sub folders.

**Attempt 2:**
I then turned to google and found [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/201110.mbox/%3C87wrc8w7kv.fsf@v35516.1blu.de%3E), which talks about the problem and then later in the thread talks about using tar or zip for the solution. This does not work either.

Has anyone else run into this? How have you worked around it?

Comment: Why do you need to preserve the dates?

Comment: I am creating a unit test for some file logic. I want to make sure my repository grabs the data from the folder with the latest last modified date.

Comment: For attempt 2, that is to say, you can try to compress your files and directories using zip or tar, and copy the .zip or .tar file to the new location, and then extract.

Comment: I tried creating a tar, copying it, and then untaring it with no luck. I am guessing there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this. I will have to wait until the ant team makes preservelastmodified work for directories like it does for files.